# How to prevent grunt-contrib-watch from self triggering?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

I have this grunt task:

```
watch: {
  files: ['resources/assets/sass/*.scss'],
  tasks: ['csscomb:sortAll', 'sass:theme', 'sass:mail']
},
csscomb: {
  options: {
    config: 'csscomb.json'
  },
  sortAll: {
    expand: true,
    cwd: '.',
    src: ['resources/assets/sass/*.scss'],
    dist: 'resources/assets/sass/',
    ext: '.scss'        
  }
},
```

When I save any scss file grunt tries to run the tasks I've specified, but csscomb:sortAll changes scss files and triggers another file change. the grunt watch runt tasks for the second time and the result is running these three tasks two times instead of once.
What would you suggest?

Comment: Remove `csscomb` from the watch task and if you wanna run `csscomb` just call it manually..?

Comment: i would configure the csscomb-task to put the output-files into another folder, and use the sass folder only for dev

Comment: please post your csscomb:sortAll config for more detailed suggestions

Comment: @aug I need both of them to run automatically on every sass file I save.

Comment: @hereandnow78 sounds like a good Idea, but the whole purpose of using csscomb was to force every team member to write their sass file in a unique format, so I need csscomb to modify the source files.

Comment: I would take a look at grunt-newer if what you are going for is simply running csscomb on the file you save.

Comment: @aug: that will not work, because the files ARE newer (they are changed). There is no solution to the problem other then the one i proposed, or what you said (remove csscomb from the watch task). if you want to force the team to stick to some rules, use a linter: https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-scss-lint

Answer (score 0):

Just use `grunt-newer`, so that the second time your task gets called, nothing actually runs:

```
watch: {
  files: ['resources/assets/sass/*.scss'],
  tasks: ['newer:csscomb:sortAll', 'newer:sass:theme', 'newer:sass:mail']
},
```